# Uninitialized variable crashes program

Tags: c++

So I have the class `IntArray`. It is what the name says it is, dynamic integer array class with bounds checking and that kind of stuff. Here's methods and variables of the class.

```
public:
    IntArray();
    IntArray(unsigned int length);
    IntArray(const IntArray& ia);
    ~IntArray();
    int length() const { return size; }
    void resize(unsigned int length);
    void insertBefore(int value, int index);
    int& operator[] (int i);
    IntArray& operator=(const IntArray& ia);
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const IntArray& array);
 private:
    unsigned int size;
    unsigned int actualSize;
    int * data;
    const static int DEFAULT = 0; // Default fill value
    const static int INCREMENT = 20; // Default value to increase size with
    void fillWithDefault(int end, int start = 0);
    void copyElements(int *toArray, int end, int start = 0, int offsetSize = 0, int offsetIndex = 0) const;
    void resize(unsigned int length, unsigned int offset);
```

And here is the main code:

```
IntArray a (6);
for ( int i =0; i <6;++ i ){
    a [ i ]= i * i ;
}
cout << "BEFORE C" << endl;
IntArray c;
cout << "AFTER C" << endl;
c = a;
```

I have tested every single function and it works, except when I launch this code it never reaches the `IntArray c;` line.

The error: This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.

Extra quirk: ran in debug, it's all good.

EDIT: extra code

```
IntArray::IntArray() {
    size = 0;
    actualSize = INCREMENT;
    data = new int[actualSize];
}

IntArray::IntArray(unsigned int length)
    : size(length), actualSize(length) {
    data = new int[length];
    fillWithDefault(length);
}

IntArray::IntArray(const IntArray& ia)
    : size(ia.size), actualSize(ia.actualSize) {
    data = new int[actualSize];
    ia.copyElements(data, size);
}

IntArray::~IntArray() {
    delete [] data;
}

void IntArray::resize(unsigned int length) {
    resize(length, length < size? length:size);
}

void IntArray::insertBefore(int value, int index) {
    resize(size+1, index);
    data[index] = value;
}

void IntArray::resize(unsigned int length, unsigned int offset) {
    unsigned int tempSize = size;
    unsigned int startIndex = offset; // Where to increase the array?
    int * theData = data;
    size = length;

    if(length > actualSize) { // Entire array needs to be copied (new data!)
        actualSize = length + INCREMENT;
        theData = new int[actualSize];
        startIndex = 0;
    }

    if(length > tempSize)
        copyElements(theData, tempSize, startIndex, (length-tempSize), offset);

    if(length > actualSize) {
        delete [] data; // Delete former data and assign new
        data = theData;
    }

    if(length > tempSize) // Fill remainder with DEFAULT
        fillWithDefault(length, offset);
}

int& IntArray::operator[] (int i) {
    if(i < 0 || (unsigned int)i >= size)
        throw "\nIndex out of bounds\n";
    return data[i];
}

IntArray& IntArray::operator=(const IntArray& ia) {
    if(this != &ia) {
        size = ia.size; // Copy variables
        actualSize = ia.actualSize;
        delete [] data; // Get rid of old data
        data = new int[actualSize]; // Create new data and copy elements
        ia.copyElements(data, size);
    }
    return *this;
}

ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const IntArray& array) {
    int size = array.size;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        out << array.data[i];
        if(i < size-1)
            out << ' ';
    }
    return out;
}

void IntArray::fillWithDefault(int end, int start) {
    if(start < 0 || start > end || (unsigned int)end > size)
        throw "\nArray can't be filled with invalid indexes\n";

    for(int i = start; i < end; i++)
            data[i] = DEFAULT;
}

void IntArray::copyElements(int *toArray, int end, int start, int offsetSize, int offsetIndex) const {
    if(start < 0 || start > end || (unsigned int)end > size)
        throw "\nArray can't be filled with invalid indexes\n";

    int offset = 0;
    for(int i = start; i < end; ++i) {
        if(i == offsetIndex)
            offset = offsetSize;
        toArray[i+offset] = data[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: It's hard to see what's going on in your code without seeing the implementations of the member functions.

Comment: Without code, we can only guess.  My guess would be something in `IntArray()` is wrong.  Crashing applications that run fine in a debugger hint at undefined behavior.

Comment: If it ran in debug mode, you probably got the benefit of a debug build that initializes uninitialized variables to something specific. However, I would venture to say that you do have uninitialized variables, but you have to show us your implementations.

Comment: not sure, but the only 'shady' thing I see myself doing is 'new int[0]'

Comment: I can only see a fillWithDefault method that excepts two parameters.

Comment: fixed the header file on top :)

Comment: What is INCREMENT?  What is DEFAULT?

Comment: wow I didn't know I forgot to copy that much code. I'm not being efficient here.. (added!)

Comment: 1) Well for sure your assignment operator is not exception safe. If new[] throws an exception in that function, you've deleted the data already and can't recover it. 2) operator [] should have two overloads - one const and for non-const functions. If you tried to pass that IntArray as a const reference, operator [] now becomes unavailable. `void foo(const IntArray& r) { cout << r[0]; }` You will see that this simple function will not compile.

Comment: Except for the two issues I mentioned concerning the exception safety and the lack of a const version of operator [], I don't see any errors.  I took the code, compiled, and ran successfully.  However, what really is your goal for this class?  There is vector<int> if you don't know already.

Comment: I know, but this is a school assignment. I'd prefer vector though. I just needed to know what I'm doing wrong to avoid mistakes like that in the future.